# Apply all possible combinations of vectors to a function using multiple cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to apply a function with all possible combinations of several variables. Another requirement is the support of multiple cores, access to global environment variables and usage of libraries.

I guess it might be a good idea to use a single matrix, and apply row by row to the function.

```
var1 = c("no", "yes")
var2 = c(TRUE, FALSE)
var3 = 1:2
combinations = expand.grid(var1,var2,var3)
```

Leading to

```
  Var1  Var2 Var3
1   no  TRUE    1
2  yes  TRUE    1
3   no FALSE    1
4  yes FALSE    1
5   no  TRUE    2
6  yes  TRUE    2
7   no FALSE    2
8  yes FALSE    2
```

The dataset I want to use is big, so I hope a dummy function is ok. Let

```
dataset
```

be a big variable, that need to be available in each run of the function and

```
library.function
```

a method from a package that is already imported.

```
calculate <- function(matrix){
  result = library.function(dataset, matrix$"Var1", matrix$"Var2", matrix$"var3")
}
```

Using for loops seems trivial, so I tried foreach / doParallel, but failed accessing environment variables and external libraries.

Comment: What does your foreach loop look like?  What kind of environment variables did the function need to get?

Comment: The `parallel` package has a function called `mclapply` which is parallelized, but not available on Windows. There is a 3rd party implementation for Windows though: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2014/07/14/implementing-mclapply-on-windows/